# How to turn a string lists into a lists?

Tags: python-3.x

There are other threads about turning strings inside a lists into different data types. I want to turn a string that is in the form of a lists into a lists. Like this: `"[5,1,4,1]" = [5,1,4,1]`

I need this because I am writing a program that requires the user to input a lists

**Example of problem:**

```
>>> x = input()
[3,4,1,5]
>>> x
'[3,4,1,5]'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean evaluate python objects like this:

```
x = eval('[3,4,1,5]');
print (x);
print(type(x) is list)

[3, 4, 1, 5]
True
```

Use this with caution as it can execute anything user will input. Better use a parser to get native lists. Use JSON for input and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) for your purpose. `eval()` is used for converting code within a string to real code:

```
>>> mystring = '[3, 5, 1, 2, 3]'
>>> mylist = eval(mystring)
>>> mylist
[3, 5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> mystring = '{4: "hello", 2:"bye"}'
>>> eval(mystring)[4]
'hello'
>>>
```

Use [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) to actually run functions:

```
>>> while True:
...     inp = raw_input('Enter your input: ')
...     exec(inp)
... 
Enter your input: print 'hello'
hello
Enter your input: x = 1
Enter your input: print x
1
Enter your input: import math
Enter your input: print math.sqrt(4)
2.0
```

In your scenario:

```
>>> x = input()
[3,4,1,5]
>>> x = eval(x)
>>> x
[3, 4, 1, 5]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys, but I would prefer not to eval() because it is unsafe.

Someone actually posted the answer that allowed me to solve this but then they deleted it. I am going to reposts that answer:

```
values = input("Enter values as lists here")
l1 = json.loads(values)
```

Comment: Using json parser to parse a Python expresssion… looks a bit like cheating =).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for this purpose.

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples,
>   lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the
>   values oneself.

```
>>> import ast
>>> val = ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
>>> val
[1, 2, 3]
```

Just remember to check that it's actually a list:

```
>>> isinstance(val, list)
True
```